# Render template in other view with another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How Can I render template with other controller to another view? I want generate 'index' template in modal, but this modal is generated in other view with other controller. So I must create objects in controller which must be setted for other 'index' action.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define all required instance variables that are used in the other controller's view and render it wherever you want with:

```
render "other_controller/action"
```

If you are sharing some element (like a modal box content), a better way would be to extract it into a shared partial (`shared/_your_partial.html.erb`) and include it in other views. That would be more modular way of doing it.

Alternatively, you might want to use a jQuery to fill out the modal box content like so:

```
$('#some-button').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#modal-box').load('controller2/index');
});
```

Comment: But I thought a better idea, which we don't must mixed two controllers to one ;)

Comment: Don't mix 2 logically different controllers, but if you have a shared functionality extract it and reuse it. Basically, SRP & DRY principles.